# Is it possible to install MOSS 2007 on Windows 7?

Tags: 2007, installation

Is it possible to install MOSS 2007 on Windows 7?

If so; how?

Answer (score 3):

While it may be possible to find some work arounds to get parts of it kind of configured, I haven't seen a solution that would really offer enough value and convenience to move away from using regular server VMs hosted on a Win7 box.

Answer (score 2):

yes, but just for development environments only. look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557253.aspx for more information.

Comment: it talks abt sharepoint 2010 . . 
I want to install Sharepoint 2007 on Windows 7 ? ?

Comment: sorr for that :) for 2007 on w7 i found this link months ago http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2009/05/07/installing-wss-3-0-moss-sp2-on-windows-7-rc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

if it is Windows 7 Ultimate or Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit. Else i am pretty sure you cannot do that